# Consulta SQL / JPQL

Tags: sql, java-ee, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Amigos, boa tarde.

Tenho uma Tabela no banco de dados chamada **Questao** Dentro da tabela eu tenho duas colunas que são **codigo (id)**  e **pergunta**. Tenho um filtro que não consigo trazer especificamente apenas código e pergunta pois o retorno do método é um objeto. Só consigo retornar o objeto inteiro.

Como faço para retornar apenas o codigo e a pergunta da tabela questão?

É como se eu fosse fazer um:

```
select codigo, pergunta from Questao where curso_codigo = ?1 and complexidade = ?2;
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o método:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Questao> geraSimuladoPorFiltro(Long codigoCurso,
            Integer complexidade, Integer numeroDeQuestoes) {
        String query = "from Questao WHERE curso_codigo = ?1 AND complexidade = ?2";
                List<Questao> questoes = manager.createQuery(query)
                .setParameter(1, codigoCurso)
                .setParameter(2, complexidade)
                .setMaxResults(numeroDeQuestoes)
                .getResultList();
        for (Questao questao : questoes) {
            System.out.println(questao.getCodigo());
            System.out.println(questao.getPergunta());
        }
        return questoes;
    }
```

Comment: Cara recupera o objeto inteiro depois itera e retira só codigo e pergunta dele... Voce gerou o toString(); na classe Questao?

Comment: Acho que essa não é uma alternativa boa, tanto a nível de processamento quanto consumo de memória, não há necessidade de se carregar mais dados do que ele vai precisar do banco, até porquê, a entidade `Questao` pode ser grande.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode retornar diretamente um `Map`, basta escrever a seguinte query:

`SELECT new Map(q.codigo, q.pergunta) FROM Questao q WHERE q.curso_codigo = ?1 AND q.complexidade = ?2`

Esta query deve retornar um objeto Map cuja chave será o código e o valor é Pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, foi perfeitamente resolvido.